# Problema com o uso do system("cls")

Tags: c++17

Esse programa é apenas para estudar nada muito serio.
Tentei usar dois meios para fazer a limpeza de tela, porem a parti do case 4 para de funcionar se eu coloco o `system ("cls")` ou a função `void clean()`, quando removo `system ("cls")` ou a função `void clean()` que é uma rotina para limpar a tela, o programa funciona normalmente.

Me perdoem a apresentação do codigo aqui no site, ainda n sei muito bem mexer aqui no site.

```
//DesafioPrincipal.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
#include <clocale>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;


void EntradaDeDadoFuncionario1(float &func1c)
{
    float func1;

    char RESP;

    do //FUNÇÃO PARA ENTRAR AS VENDAS DO FUNCIONARIO 1
    {
        cout <<"Entre o valor total de venda do Funcionario 1"<< endl;
        cin >> func1;
        func1c = func1c + func1;
        cout << "Deseja inserir novas Vendas para este funcionario?" << endl;
        cin >> RESP;
        cin.ignore(80 ,'\n');
    }
    while (RESP == 'S' or RESP == 's');
}


void EntradaDeDadoFuncionario2(float &func2c)
{
    float func2;
    char RESP;

    do
    {
        cout << "Entre o valor total de vendas do funcionario 2" << endl;
        cin >> func2;
        func2c += func2;
        cout << "Deseja Inserir novas vendas para este funcionario?" << endl;
        cin >> RESP;
        cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    }
    while (RESP == 'S' or RESP == 's');
}

void EntradaDeDadoFuncionario3(float &func3c)
{
    float func3;
    char RESP;

    do
    {
        cout << "Entre o valor total de vendas do funcionario 3" << endl;
        cin >> func3;
        func3c += func3;
        cout << "Deseja Inserir novas vendas para este funcionario?" << endl;
        cin >> RESP;
        cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    }
    while (RESP == 'S' or RESP == 's');
}

void totalVendas(float Func1C, float Func2C, float Func3C)
{
    float TotalDeVendas = Func1C + Func2C + Func3C;
    cout << "Teste da Funcao: " << TotalDeVendas << endl;
}
void clear (void) //Rotina para limpar a tela 
{
    HANDLE TELA;
    DWORD ESCRITA = 0;
    COORD POS;
    TELA = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    POS.X= 0;
    POS.Y= 0;
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(TELA, 32, 80 * 25, POS, &ESCRITA);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(TELA, POS);
}


void TestaValores(float func1C, float func2C, float func3C){
    cout << "O total de venda do funcionario 1 e .......: "<< func1C << endl;
    cout << "O total de venda do funcionario 2 e .......: "<< func2C << endl;
    cout << "O total de venda do funcionario 3 e .......:"<< func3C << endl;
    cout << "Resultado da soma na Main ..:"<< (func1C + func2C + func3C) << endl;
}

int main(void){

    setlocale (LC_ALL,"");

    float func1C = 0, func2C = 0, func3C = 0;

    int OPCAO = 0;

    cout << setprecision (2);
    cout << setiosflags(ios::right);
    cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed);
    cout << "\n";

    while(OPCAO != 5)
    {
        cout << "--------------------" << endl;
        cout << "-Controle de Vendas-" << endl;
        cout << "---Menu Principal----" << endl;
        cout << "--------------------" << endl;
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "[1] --Funcionario 1--" << endl;
        cout << "[2] --Funcionario 2--" << endl;
        cout << "[3] --Funcionario 3--" << endl;
        cout << "[4] -Total De Vendas-" << endl;
        cout << "[5] -Fim do Programa-" << endl;

        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Escolha uma opcao:";
        cin>> OPCAO;
        cin.ignore(80 , '\n');

        switch (OPCAO)
           {
               case 1:
                    EntradaDeDadoFuncionario1(func1C);
                    break;
               case 2:
                    EntradaDeDadoFuncionario2(func2C);
                    break;
               case 3:
                    EntradaDeDadoFuncionario3(func3C);
                    break;
               case 4:
                    totalVendas(func1C, func2C, func3C);
                    break;
                defaul:
                    cout << "Entre com uma opção válida!" << endl;
                    break;
           }
    }


    TestaValores(func1C,func2C,func3C);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mas qual o erro que dá ? O que o programa faz que não deveria fazer ? O que quer dizer com "para de funcionar" ? Qual a linha exata onde colocou o `system(cls)` ? Já agora tem uma gralha de escrita, em que escreveu `defaul` quando deveria ser `default`.

Comment: Outra coisa: note que em suas funções você passa como parâmetro o endereço de uma variável mas não utiliza o conteúdo desse endereço para acumular mas sim o próprio endereço. Se você passa uma variável como parâmetro não redefina tal variável no corpo da função.

Comment: A partir do Case 4 da função main ele simplesmente não realiza a função que foi colocar no case 4, ele até chega a aparecer a função na tela porém logo some.

Comment: O system eu coloco no começo ou no final do while, porém de ambos os modos da o mesmo erro, o case 4 simplesmente não executa com deveria, apresentar o  total de vendas.

Comment: Desculpa, não entendi o que você quiser dizer sobre a queles de passar por referência, poderia me explicar???

Comment: Talvez seu programa esteja em C++ e o system("cls") funciona em C.
Ent salva o arquivo em C e tenta dnv. Funcionou cmg :)